# Unable to get NiFi to work in cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, apache-nifi

Based on all the examples I've read I thought setting up NiFi as a cluster would be easy. Apparently I can't get it to work. I'm using NiFi 1.5. I only have 2 host and pretended that there was a third, but NiFi is not starting as a cluster. These are the changes I've made to the config files. 
state-management.xml file

```
<cluster-provider>
    <id>zk-provider</id>
    <class>org.apache.nifi.controller.state.providers.zookeeper.ZooKeeperStateProvider</class>
    <property name="Connect String">etl-1:2181,etl-2:2181,etl-3:2181</property>
    <property name="Root Node">/ssd/nifi-1.5.0</property>
    <property name="Session Timeout">10 seconds</property>
    <property name="Access Control">Open</property>
</cluster-provider>
```

zookeeper.properities file

```
dataDir=./state/zookeeper   
server.1=etl-1:2888:3888
server.2=etl-2:2888:3888
server.3=etl-3:2888:3888
```

nifi.properties file

```
nifi.zookeeper.connect.string=etl-1:2181,etl-2:2181,etl-3:2181
nifi.zookeeper.root.node=/ssd/nifi-1.5.0
nifi.cluster.is.node=yes
nifi.cluster.node.address=etl-2  (this is set to etl-1 on the other node)
nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start=true
```

[nifi@etl-2 zookeeper]$ cat /ssd/nifi-1.5.0/state/zookeeper/myid
2
[nifi@etl-1 logs]$ cat /ssd/nifi-1.5.0/state/zookeeper/myid
1

I've updated logback.xml to DEBUG, but there are so many message I can't seem to find out's what wrong. My best guess is that zookeeper in starting in local instead of cluster.

```
ls -l /ssd/nifi-1.5.0/state/
total 4
drwxrwxr-x. 18 nifi nifi 4096 Feb 23 18:49 local
drwxrwxr-x.  2 nifi nifi   18 Feb 23 15:26 zookeeper
```

Comment: I believe you need 3 "real" nodes for the ZK quorum

Comment: it's possible but I'm not convinced. I don't see any error about a failed quorum. In fact I don't see any message that the cluster is even attempting to start.

Comment: It might not be a ZK problem per se, but rather an assumption made by NiFi that there are 3 real nodes in the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I had nifi.cluster.is.node=yes instead of nifi.cluster.is.node=true.

Answer (score 0):

Am trying to run Nifi as a 3 node cluster on Windows 10, with same properties set in all 3 conf files as mentioned above, but still its failing to start nifi as a 3 node cluster. 
Below are the settings done on my files

state-management.xml file

```
<cluster-provider>
    <id>zk-provider</id>
    <class>org.apache.nifi.controller.state.providers.zookeeper.ZooKeeperStateProvider</class>
    <property name="Connect String">node1:2181,node2:2181,node3:2181</property>
    <property name="Root Node">/nifi</property>
    <property name="Session Timeout">10 seconds</property>
    <property name="Access Control">Open</property>
</cluster-provider>
```

zookeper properties

```
dataDir=./state/zookeeper
autopurge.snapRetainCount=30
server.1=node1:2888:3888
server.2=node2:2888:3888
server.3=node3:2888:3888
```

nifi properties:

```
nifi.web.http.host=node1
nifi.web.http.port=8080
nifi.cluster.is.node=true
nifi.cluster.node.address=node1
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.port=11122
nifi.zookeeper.connect.string=node1:2181,node2:2181,node3:2181
nifi.zookeeper.root.node=/nifi
```

In other 2 noes, the host name are placed respectively

But when i start the nodes, it displays the below error
C:\nifi-1.11.0-bin\Node1\bin>run-nifi.bat

2020-02-11 20:29:20,237 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Starting Apache NiFi...

2020-02-11 20:29:20,238 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Working Directory: C:\NIFI-1~1.0-B\Node1

2020-02-11 20:29:20,239 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Command: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin\java.exe -classpath C:\NIFI-1~1.0-B\Node1.\conf;C:\NIFI-1~1.0-B\Node1.\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0-B\Node1.\lib\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.26.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0-B\Node1.\lib\jetty-schemas-3.1.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0-B\Node1.\lib\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.26.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0-B\Node1.\lib\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.26.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0-B\Node1.\lib\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0-B\Node1.\lib\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0-B\Node1.\lib\nifi-api-1.11.0.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0-B\Node1.\lib\nifi-framework-api-1.11.0.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0-B\Node1.\lib\nifi-nar-utils-1.11.0.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0-B\Node1.\lib\nifi-properties-1.11.0.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0-B\Node1.\lib\nifi-runtime-1.11.0.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0-B\Node1.\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199=true -Xmx512m -Xms512m -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom -Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=sun.net.www.protocol -Dzookeeper.admin.enableServer=false -Dnifi.properties.file.path=C:\NIFI-1~1.0-B\Node1.\conf\nifi.properties -Dnifi.bootstrap.listen.port=53535 -Dapp=NiFi -Dorg.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.log.dir=C:\NIFI-1~1.0-B\Node1\bin..\logs org.apache.nifi.NiFi

2020-02-11 20:29:20,554 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Failed to set permissions so that only the owner can read pid file C:\NIFI-1~1.0-B\Node1\bin..\run\nifi.pid; this may allows others to have access to the key needed to communicate with NiFi. Permissions should be changed so that only the owner can read this file

2020-02-11 20:29:20,561 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Failed to set permissions so that only the owner can read status file C:\NIFI-1~1.0-B\Node1\bin..\run\nifi.status; this may allows others to have access to the key needed to communicate with NiFi. Permissions should be changed so that only the owner can read this file

2020-02-11 20:29:20,573 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Launched Apache NiFi with Process ID 4284

C:\nifi-1.11.0-bin\Node1\bin>status-nifi.bat

20:31:57.265 [main] DEBUG org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.NotificationServiceManager - Found 0 service elements

20:31:57.271 [main] INFO org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.NotificationServiceManager - Successfully loaded the following 0 services: []

20:31:57.272 [main] INFO org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi - Registered no Notification Services for Notification Type NIFI_STARTED

20:31:57.273 [main] INFO org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi - Registered no Notification Services for Notification Type NIFI_STOPPED

20:31:57.274 [main] INFO org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi - Registered no Notification Services for Notification Type NIFI_DIED

20:31:57.277 [main] DEBUG org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command - Status File: C:\NIFI-1~1.0-B\Node1\bin..\run\nifi.status

20:31:57.278 [main] DEBUG org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command - Status File: C:\NIFI-1~1.0-B\Node1\bin..\run\nifi.status

20:31:57.279 [main] DEBUG org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command - Properties: {pid=4284, port=53536}

20:31:57.280 [main] DEBUG org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command - Pinging 53536

20:31:58.343 [main] DEBUG org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command - Process with PID 4284 is not running

20:31:58.345 [main] INFO org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command - Apache NiFi is not running